# In Angular 8 should I define the data returned from a Spring Boot rest call as an interface or a class?

Tags: angular, typescript

A newbie question.  Reviewing some online tutorials I see some examples where the Angular data structure used to hold the rest call result is defined as an interface, others where it is defined as a class. What’s the difference?

Answer (score 0):

### Interface

One of TypeScript’s core principles is that type checking focuses on the shape that values have. This is sometimes called “duck typing” or “structural subtyping”.

In TypeScript, interfaces fill the role of naming these types, and are a powerful way of defining contracts within your code as well as contracts with code outside of your project.

### Class

Traditional JavaScript uses functions and prototype-based inheritance to build up reusable components, but this may feel a bit awkward to programmers more comfortable with an object-oriented approach, where classes inherit functionality and objects are built from these classes.

Starting with ECMAScript 2015, also known as ECMAScript 6, JavaScript programmers will be able to build their applications using this object-oriented class-based approach. In TypeScript, we allow developers to use these techniques now, and compile them down to JavaScript that works across all major browsers and platforms, without having to wait for the next version of JavaScript

Comment: I understand the difference between a class and an interface.  What I don't understand is why the Angular structure used to capture the Spring Boot rest api call would be defined as an interface

Comment: When transpiled to javascript, interface is nothing, and class is es6 class or prototype, which will add more types to javascript, since the json  from server are just contracts, do not have client type, interface is better than class.